# Code optimization: Sum integer values for specific string,

Tags: java, string, java-me, integer, sum

I am writing jave-me(Java ME 3.2) MIDlet, where I use variables for Mode,Fan and Temperature(this one is simple). When I send information to web API, i have to change them to Hex values, because API reads them as bits.
Response to web API is in this format:AABBCC
AA:mode - 8 bits (Auto,Low,Cool,Wind,Heat,N/A,N/A,OnOff)
BB:fanSpeed - 8 bits (Auto,Low,Med, High,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A)
CC:temperature - Integer

So to generate this response, currently I use this code. But it could probably be a lot shorter or simpler. So how could I optimize this code:

```
int firstPart = 0;
    int seccondPart = 0;
    if(climateOn)
    {
        firstPart += 128;
    }
    if(mode.equals("HEAT"))
    {
        firstPart += 16;
    }
    if(mode.equals("WIND"))
    {
        firstPart += 8;
    }
    if(mode.equals("COOL"))
    {
        firstPart += 4;
    }
    if(mode.equals("LOW"))
    {
        firstPart += 2;
    }
    if(mode.equals("AUTO"))
    {
        firstPart += 1;
    }
    if(fanSpeed.equals("HIGH"))
    {
        seccondPart += 8;
    }
    if(fanSpeed.equals("MED"))
    {
        seccondPart += 4;
    }
    if(fanSpeed.equals("LOW"))
    {
        seccondPart += 2;
    }
    if(fanSpeed.equals("AUTO"))
    {
        seccondPart += 1;
    }
    return Integer.toHexString(firstPart) + ""  + Integer.toHexString(seccondPart) + "" +(setTemperature + 19);
```

Comment: This one is probably for the http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Didn't know about this web page, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 7 or later, you can use `switch` statement:

```
switch (mode) {
    case "HEAT": firstPart += 16; break;
    case "WIND": firstPart += 8; break;
    // ...
}
```

Another solution is to put this data in maps:

```
static final Map<String, Integer> modes = new HashMap<>();
static {
    modes.put("HEAT", 16);
    modes.put("WIND", 8);
    // ...
}

void someMethod(String mode) {
    // ...
    if (modes.containsKey(mode))
        firstPart += modes.get(mode);
}
```

You can also use enums like this:

```
enum Mode {
    HEAT(16), WIND(8), COOL(4), LOW(2), AUTO(1);
    private final int value;
    private Mode(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public int getValue() {return value;}
}

void someMethod() {
    // ...
    Mode mode = Mode.valueOf(str); // finds the named element. throws IllegalArgumentException
    firstPart += mode.getValue();
}
```

[EDIT]
You can even do one better with enums:

```
enum Mode {
    AUTO, LOW, COOL, WIND, HEAT;

    public int getValue() { return 1 << ordinal(); }
}
```

The `ordinal()` method returns the ordinal number of the specific constant in the enum, starting from 0. This means, that it will return 0 for `AUTO`, 1 for `LOW`, etc. And the `1 << N` is a fast way to compute 2 to power N.

The good thing about this is, that it automatically produces the correct value (assuming the order is right) and it won't produce the same value for two enums.

The usage is the same as with previous enum implementation.

Comment: As I already wrote, I use java ME. Added it version in question description, so I can't use enums or maps and I can only use integers inside switch statments.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know Java ME is so restricted. Still `Hashtable` seems to be available, so you should be able to use that. It's very similar to the map case.

Comment: You are right Hashtable is available. I will try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about [java enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)? Here's an example:

```
public enum Mode {
  Auto,Low,Cool,Wind,Heat,NA,OnOff;
}
```

Enums can be used in switch statements.

Also you can assign each one of those values with a byte value too.

Comment: Can't use enum in jave-me (atleast this version).